# Appending two texts keeping the line structure

Tags: python

Sorry in advance if my question is not smart enough, but I am new in Python:
I have two string files: file A and file B. The are something like this:
File A:

```
File A is the master file{
 sdfsf
 sdfsdf
 sdfsd
 sdfdf
}
```

File B is similar.
I want to append file A to file B(and to other files later), but when I try to append it with "with open" it is in one line. I want to manipulate it line by line(to add or remove lines, so I need it to be list), so I am making it list separated by lines, but later, when I try to append it to the other file it is not the same line structure or the text is on one line.
So I have tried this and again it doesn't work:

import os

```
 file_A=open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\...\\Sofa.txt').readlines()

file_B = open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\.... ....\\....\\...\\view_1.txt', 'a') 
for line in File_A: 
 write.line

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `readlines()` return a list of strings, if you want to concatenate the lists you can do:

```
full_file = File_A + File_B
```

Now you have a list of all the lines in the files (the ones in File_A first ) and you can manipulate it:

```
for line in full_file:
    write(line)
```

Comment: The lines you get from `readlines` will already have newlines at the end.

Answer (score 1):

To append the contents of File_A to File_B, you can just treat it as a single string.

```
with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\...\\Sofa.txt') as file_a:
    contents_a = file_a.read()

with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\.... ....\\....\\...\\view_1.txt', 'a') as file_b:
    file_b.write(contents_a)
```